# Eliminate dataframe rows that match a character string

Tags: r, filter, subset, dplyr, grepl

I have a dataframe `rawdata` with columns that contain ecological information. I am trying to eliminate all of the rows for which the column `LatinName` matches a vector of species for which I already have some data, and create a new dataframe with only the species that are missing data. So, what I'd like to do is something like:

```
matches <- c("Thunnus thynnus", "Balaenoptera musculus", "Homarus americanus") 
# obviously these are a random subset; the real vector has ~16,000 values 
rawdata_missing <- rawdata %>% filter(LatinName != "matches")
```

This doesn't work because the boolean operator can't be applied to a character string. Alternatively I could do something like this:

```
rawdata_missing <- filter(rawdata, !grepl(matches, LatinName)
```

This doesn't work either because `!grepl` also can't use the character string.

I know there are a lot of ways I could subset `rawdata` using the rows where `LatinName` IS in `matches`, but I can't figure out a neat way to subset `rawdata` such that `LatinName` is NOT in `matches`.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Just negate the `%in%` operator - `rawdata %>% filter(!(LatinName %in% matches))`

Comment: @thelatemail's method is the way to go here. But for future reference, if you do need to turn a string vector into a regular expression that can be used by `grepl` or `grep` you can do, for example `match.string = paste(matches, collapse="|")`.

Comment: @thelatemail that is perfect! Thank you. I just didn't know how to write the negate operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filteredData <- rawdata[!(rawdata$LatinName %in% Matches), ]
```

Comment: Thank you! This works as does negating the %in% as shown above :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way by using subset, paste, mapply and grepl is...

`fileteredData <- subset(rawdata,mapply(grepl,rawdata$LatinName,paste(Matches,collapse = "|")) == FALSE)`